# Is there a recommended approach to replace the reserved type column in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that needs a type column, but it's not for single table inheritance. Is there a recommended way or workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just change the [inheritance_column](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-inheritance_column):

> Defines the name of the table column which will store the class name
> on single-table inheritance situations.
>
> The default inheritance column name is type, which means it's a
> reserved word inside Active Record. To be able to use single-table
> inheritance with another column name, or to use the column type in
> your own model for something else, you can set inheritance_column:
>
> `self.inheritance_column = 'zoink'`

If you're not using STI you can set it to whatever you want. The end result is exactly the same as as with models that don't have a *type* column.

Comment: would you consider this a normal (industry) practice or something to be avoided (workaround)?

Comment: Its a pretty well documented and stable feature.